# Remote EJB not found

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, deployment, wildfly

I have an EJB deployed in an EAR:

```
@Stateless
@Remote(ActorProvider.class)
public class ActorServiceClient implements Serializable, ActorProvider { ... }
```

Here is the remote interface:

```
@Remote
public interface ActorProvider { ... }
```

Now, I have a separate WAR being deployed with the following class:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class ShiroStartup implements IShiroStartup {
    @EJB 
    ActorProvider actorProvider;
...
}
```

The idea being that I deploy my actor service in an EAR, and I separately deploy a client project that gets the `ActorProvider` which Shiro uses for authorization (this is ancillary, but what I'm using it for).

I get an error starting the `ShiroStartup` (after I have deployed the EAR with the provider in it):

> > No EJB found with interface of type 'consumers.ActorProvider' for binding realm.ShiroStartup/actorProvider

Why can't I do this?  If I put the Provider in the war with the ShiroStartup it works fine, but it will not inject across deployments.  Why is that?  This is Wildfly 9 using JavaEE 7.

Comment: You should browse your Wildfly JNDI tree to see whether your EJB was correctly deployed. If it was then, based on its JNDI path, you should do the EJB lookup like this: @EJB(lookup="*java:global/<module-name>/<distinct-name>/<bean-name>!<fully-qualified-classname-of-the-remote-interface>*"). Here's a [related issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-3455).

Answer (score 1):

1., The EJB and WAR modules should take place in the same EAR

or

2., Include the EJB jar into the classpath of the WAR

or :)

3., with portable JNDI names (for remote interfaces):
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/girgn/index.html

In particular: java:app[/module name]/enterprise bean name[/interface name]

Comment: So there is no way to do it otherwise?

Comment: I have added another (3rd) option :)